# Getting arguments for register_post_type from a plugin generated post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I’ve taken over website from another developer and they used a plugin to generate a custom post type. The plugin is no longer maintained and is causing an error 505 when try and load the plugins admin page. The front end site works fine.

So I was wondering if there was anyway to get arguments for use in `register_post_type()` for the post type that is generated by the plugin so that don't have to use the plugin? The plugin still works it's just it courses and error 505 on plugins admin page, all plugin pages work but unfortunately there is no export option for that can be used to give me arguments for `register_post_type()`.

The plugin is [Toolset Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/)  if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I was wondering if there was anyway to get arguments for use in `register_post_type` for the post type that is generated by the plugin so that don't have to use the plugin?

You can use `get_post_type_object( string $post_type )`. See Documentation and example usage **[here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_object/#user-contributed-notes)**.

```
$obj = get_post_type_object( 'certification' );

print_r( $obj );
```

Above code might return something like this, so you can get the arguments used by `register_post_type ()`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [labels] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Certification
            [singular_name] => Certification
            [add_new] => Add New
            [add_new_item] => Add New Certification
            [edit_item] => Edit Certification
            [new_item] => New Page
            [view_item] => View Certification
            [search_items] => Search Certification
            [not_found] => Not found
            [not_found_in_trash] => Not found in Trash
            [parent_item_colon] => Parent Certification:
            [all_items] => All Certifications
            [menu_name] => Certifications
            [update_item] => Update Certification
            [name_admin_bar] => Certification
        )
    [description] => Certifications
    [public] => 1
    [hierarchical] => 1
    [exclude_from_search] => 
    [publicly_queryable] => 1
    [show_ui] => 1
    [show_in_menu] => 
    [show_in_nav_menus] => 1
    [show_in_admin_bar] => 1
    [menu_position] => 5
    [menu_icon] => dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus
    [capability_type] => post
    [map_meta_cap] => 1
    [register_meta_box_cb] => 
    [taxonomies] => Array
        (
            [0] => objective
        )
    [has_archive] => 1
    [rewrite] => Array
        (
            [slug] => certification
            [with_front] => 1
            [pages] => 1
            [feeds] => 1
            [ep_mask] => 1
        )
    [query_var] => certification
    [can_export] => 1
    [delete_with_user] => 
    [_builtin] => 
    [_edit_link] => post.php?post=%d
    [label] => Certification
    [name] => certification
    [cap] => stdClass Object
        (
            [edit_post] => edit_post
            [read_post] => read_post
            [delete_post] => delete_post
            [edit_posts] => edit_posts
            [edit_others_posts] => edit_others_posts
            [publish_posts] => publish_posts
            [read_private_posts] => read_private_posts
            [read] => read
            [delete_posts] => delete_posts
            [delete_private_posts] => delete_private_posts
            [delete_published_posts] => delete_published_posts
            [delete_others_posts] => delete_others_posts
            [edit_private_posts] => edit_private_posts
            [edit_published_posts] => edit_published_posts
            [create_posts] => edit_posts
        )
)
```

I hope this may helps.

Comment: Thanks. That's great worked a treat!

Comment: @lomokev glad to know that it helped. Please mark this an **Accepted Answer** to help other people searching for  similar issues, Thanks.